# jQuery Print The exact displayed page format

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, printing

I want to print a part of page like `<div id="printablearea"> ... </div>`

at now I use this:

```
$('a.Print').click(function () {
  $('div#printablearea').printElement();
  return false;
});
```

but there is a problem to use this way and that is the display elements in page are different from printed page. For example all of my elements are right to left but in printed page all of them are left to right, or fonts are different in printed page.

So is there any way to use `jQuery printElement` to print exactly the displayed page, and if not, what is your suggestion? I just have two limitations:

1-The exact displayed page format

2-I want print part of page not all of them

Answer (score 0):

You can override the css for the print if you're having formatting issues:

```
$("selector").printElement(
        {
        overrideElementCSS:[
    'thisWillBeTheCSSUsed.css',
    { href:'thisWillBeTheCSSUsedAsWell.css',media:'print'}]
        });
```

or

```
 $("selector").printElement(
        {
        printBodyOptions:
        {
        styleToAdd:'padding:10px;margin:10px;color:#FFFFFF !important;',
        classNameToAdd : 'thisWillBeTheClassUsedAsWell'
        }
        });
```

Documentation from the site: http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/

Comment: I use the same plug-in and same command as mentioned in question but how can I solve my limitations?

Comment: if you mean I must add my css file I use a lot of css files in pages, how can I add all of them?